# Get Records from 'in' query list which are not present in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using a query having 'in' clause with around 500 records in oracle 11g, Is there any way to fetch the records from 'in' clause whose value is not present in the table.

**Example:**

Query:

> select * from table where name in
>   ('NICK','TOM','LUCY','HARRY','RAFEL');

Sample Table:

[image]

In the above table, records for 'TOM', 'HARRY', 'RAFEL' is not present in table which are present in in clause, So the output should be:

```
TOM

HARRY

RAFEL
```

Comment: I don't understand clearly what your exact issue is. Use NOT IN ?

Comment: i don't want to fetch the records from the table, i want to fetch the records from the that is name from in clause which is not present in table.

Comment: You would have to put the superset of 'NICK','TOM','LUCY','HARRY','RAFEL' into some table or CTE

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a set with the values you are looking for, then perform a join with your referential table to search non matching records:

```
with cte_in as  (
select 'NICK' nickname from dual
union all select 'TOM' from dual
union all select 'LUCY' from dual
union all select 'HARRY' from dual
union all select 'RAFEL' from dual
)
SELECT    nickname 
FROM      cte_in cte
LEFT JOIN mytable mt
       ON cte.nickname = mt.NAME
WHERE     mt.NAME IS NULL
```

other solution is using `MINUS`

```
SELECT nickname
FROM   cte_in
minus
select name 
from   mytable
```

EDIT: an other solution to stay close to the `IN` format

```
WITH cte_in
     AS ( SELECT ( column_value ).getstringval() nickname
          FROM   XMLTABLE('"NICK","TOM","LUCY","HARRY","RAFEL"') ) 
SELECT *
FROM   cte_in
minus
SELECT NAME
FROM   mytable;
```

See Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/679ae/11

Comment: where is 'in' query here? you need to use 'in' query.

Comment: the simplest/fastest way seems to insert all values in the `IN` inside a table, then perform a `minus` or an `outer join`. There is no reasons to absolutly try to use an `IN` clause if there is an other solution wich fits the need

Comment: But question asks to use the 'in' query.